# Parsing and Jumping into the next block in JSON file with Swift 2.0

Tags: json, swift

I am currently learning how to fetch and parse a JSON file in Swift 2.0.

**This is the example JSON file i was provided from a friend**

```
{
  "name": "Busitevent",
  "count": 398,
  "frequency": "Every 30 mins",
  "version": 93,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "nextrun": "Wed Feb 10 2016 02:43:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "thisversionrun": "Wed Feb 10 2016 02:13:19 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "eventTitles": {
          "href": "https://events.ucsc.edu/event/3338",
          "text": "32nd Annual Martin Luther King Jr. Convocation featuring Alicia Garza"
        },
        "eventDates": "",
        "eventDescription": "",
        "index": 1,
        "url": "https://events.ucsc.edu/"
      }
}
```

I am trying to pattern match "collection1" so i can convert it into an object

**This is what i've got so far (Replaced the url with a fake one)**

```
let url = NSURL(string: "www.jsonsourcefile.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var names = [String]()

        do {
            let json : NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            if let collection1 : NSArray = json["collection1"] as? NSArray{
                print("you got it")
                        //names.append(collection1)
    }


        } catch {
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }

        print(names) // ["Bloxus test", "Manila Test"]

    }
```

So the main problem i am facing is that collection1 isn't being matched by my if-statement, and i am not sure why.

Comment: Have you tried `json["results"]["collection1"]` or `json["results"][0]["collection1"]`.

Comment: You have provided an invalid JSON, can you update with a valid JSON?

Comment: Try parsing the json (a valid one) using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) (I find it makes handling json in swift very simple)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first fetch the `results` dictionary before trying to retrieve the `collections1` array. Code provided below would give you a good understanding of how you will have to parse JSON without any 3rd party parsers.

> Sample JSON: (Since the question didn't have a valid JSON)

```
{
    "employees":[{
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Doe"
        },
        {
            "firstName":"Anna",
            "lastName":"Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName":"Peter",
            "lastName":"Jones"
    }]
}
```

In the above JSON, you will have to note the following,

- Its a dictionary of objects
- `employees` object is an array of dictionaries

To fetch the value for `firstName`, you will have to do nested `if let` blocks to get the data.

```
var jsonString = "{\"employees\":[{\"firstName\":\"John\", \"lastName\":\"Doe\"},{\"firstName\":\"Anna\", \"lastName\":\"Smith\"},{\"firstName\":\"Peter\", \"lastName\":\"Jones\"}]}"

do {
    let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let json: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

    if let employees = json["employees"] as? [NSDictionary] {
        for employee in employees {
            if let firstName = employee["firstName"] {
                print("First name ===> \(firstName)")
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print("failure")
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error while parsing data ===> \(error)")
}
```

**Note:** The complexity of the nested `if let`s would be higher if have to parse larger JSON. There are 3rd party Swift JSON parsers (like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)) which would simplify the way you access objects. SwiftyJSON uses syntax similar to the one mentioned by @kye.